# No value given to one or more parameters

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2010

So I input some data into textbox then I click this button

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      command.Connection = connect;
      if (idkaryawantxt.Text != "")
       {
            string q = "UPDATE tableAbsensi SET Absen_keluar =('" + (DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm")) + "') WHERE ID ='" + idkaryawantxt.Text.ToString() + "' AND Tanggal ='" + (DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")) +"'";
            dosomething(q);
       }
       this.Close();
    }
```

Then it says

> No value given to one or more parameters

The table looked like this :
[image]

Comment: What is your `dosomething` methods do? Did you debug your code? Which line you get this error?

Comment: `idkaryawantxt.Text.ToString()` never use user input directly. Validate your input and use SQL parameters. Otherwise your solution is vulnerable to SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check not only if `idkaryawantxt` is empty but also if it is not null:

```
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(idkaryawantxt.Text))
    {
        var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now; 
        string q = "UPDATE tableAbsensi SET Absen_keluar ='" 
            + currentDateTime.ToString("hh:mm") + "' WHERE ID ='" 
            + idkaryawantxt.Text + "' AND Tanggal ='" 
            + currentDateTime.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") +"'";

        dosomething(q);
    }
```

Secondly the brackets here `(DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm"))`and here `(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))` are not needed.

You do not need to convert `idkaryawantxt.Text` to string (`idkaryawantxt.Text.ToString()`), as it is already a string.

You do not need brackets here `SET Absen_keluar =('"`and here `"') WHERE ID ='"` .

What is more it might be useful to set the `DateTime.Now` to a variable instead of calling it twice, because in some exceptional cases it could give you two different values.

And finally: avoid creating your queries in the way you did in this case. It is not an elegant way of creating queries + it is not secured against SQL injections.

Comment: It might be helpful to state what you have changed in the code :)

Comment: The only chance that using `DateTime.Now` is a problem here is when the date changes in between. This is very unlikely to happen.